# Nhibernate query over

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Im trying to select only some fields from my table with code like this

```
IList<Product> res = sess.QueryOver<Product>()            
             .Select(x =>x.name)           
             .List<Product>();
```

No errors with this code but in runtime i got this: "Unable to perform find[SQL: SQL not available]" the value "Prod1 is not of type SympleFlhLINQ.Product and and cannot be used on this generic collection".

And will be very nice if someone tell me how i can fetch only product name and referenced category name width something like this

```
 IList<Product> res = sess.QueryOver<Product>() 
                .Select(x =>x.name)
                .Select(x=>x.Cat.CategoryName)
                .List<Product>();
```

Comment: Do you need an `IList<Product>` or can you use a DTO?

Comment: DTO u mean use type like     public class ProductCollection : List<Product>
    {
    }??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
IList<string> names = sess.QueryOver<Product>()            
         .Select(x =>x.Name)
         .List<string>();
```

or

```
ProductDto product = null;
Category category = null;
IList<ProductDto> res = sess.QueryOver<Product>()
    .JoinAlias(x => x.Category, () => category)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(x => x.Name).WithAlias(() => product.Name)
        .Select(() => category.Name).WithAlias(() => product.CategoryName))
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ProductDto>())
    .List<ProductDto>();
```

Comment: im newbie in stackoverflow and i dont know how i can accept the answer LOL. sry